# Utility to anti-crop an image

Tags: image-processing, image-editor

I have a photograph which is not wide enough for the banner space I'm trying to fill.  If I crop the top and bottom, the photograph loses its meaning.  The background is a simple lake scene so I think a reasonably smart utility could extrapolate and extend the background pretty easily.

I'd like to use a free online utility to anti-crop the image.

Comment: Are you looking for an app, PC/Mac application, website?  There's a couple of well-regarded iOS apps that do this.

Comment: @fsb - I'd prefer an online utility if possible.  Failing that, a program that runs on a PC.

Comment: It can't be possible. Anyone can convert the image to another format and edit